# GlassFish 4.0 as a windows 7 service

Tags: service, glassfish, restart, glassfish-4, asadmin

I am using GlassFish 4.0 in a cluster configuration with two nodes and each node has one instance. The DAS and two instances are setup as Window 7 services that use a logon account that has administrator privileges.  Upon starting the machine the service starts and the DAS is up along with the instances. From Windows Task Manager this appears as two java.exe processes per service for a total of 6 java.exe's. The problem is that if I use the `asadmin restart-domain` command two new java.exe processes spawn and the two old ones do not die. The application that is deployed works fine, but with enough restarts using asadmin, the memory starts to fill up from zombie java.exe's.  Oddly enough running `asadmin stop-domain` will stop the two DAS java.exe processes but then running `asadmin start-domain` starts Glassfish as a non-service.  The only way to start the DAS back as a service is to run "sc start domain1" or restart the machine.  Also, the only way to stop the DAS java.exe processes is with asadmin; stopping the service using "sc stop domain1" stalls and does not work. It is also odd that each service (DAS, instance 1 and 2) starts two java.exe's, vs starting only one each when running as a non-service.

Is there any additional service wrapper configuration that needs to be done, or asadmin options that need to be passed in when running `asadmin` commands on GlassFish 4.0 running as a service?

Answer (score 1):

These may be helpful.  The implementation for 4 is the same as 3.1

https://blogs.oracle.com/foo/entry/automatic_starting_of_servers_in

https://blogs.oracle.com/foo/entry/automatic_starting_implementation_details_for

Comment: I saw the explanation of the two java processes.  Thanks.